# Graph Theory, Wheel Graphs

Tags: math, graph-theory

According to [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graph_theory/types_of_graphs.htm) , wheel graph is obtained from a cycle graph Cn-1 by adding a new vertex. That new vertex is called a Hub which is connected to all the vertices of Cn.

Notation − Wn

```
No. of edges in Wn = No. of edges from hub to all other vertices +
                     No. of edges from all other nodes in cycle graph without a hub.
                     = (n–1) + (n–1)
                     = 2(n–1)
```

Example

Take a look at the following graphs. They are all wheel graphs.
[image]

Wheel Graph

In graph I, it is obtained from C3 by adding an vertex at the middle named as ‘d’. It is denoted as W4.

Now, the question is, can a Hub exist outside of the shape? not in the center?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, unless you are considering [geometric graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory). That is, when dealing with graphs defined by a set of vertices, V, and a set of edges, E, that is all what matters and a picture like this is just one (though really making it clear how we may interpret those graphs) out of infinitely many possible representations of (V,E). In particular, any of those vertices could be wherever you want as long as they all are there and the edges connect what they are supposed to connect.

Positions of vertices start to matter when thinking in geometric terms. Then vertices may have specific coordinates, edges may have specific lengths, etc.

Comment: Got it. was confused about the term wheel. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse it can be outside of the shape unless there is no  planarity criteria.